# vba error code in form

Tags: excel, forms, vba

hey, first thanks to all for answering my other questions. I am extremely new to Excel VBA and some things I just get hung up on. I have a userform (not embedded in a worksheet) and I have a few fields that are for currency (amounts, etc) and if someone inputs a letter it errors after they hit the command button and they lose all info. I need error code to where I can tell them in a msgbox that they should not put characters in a currency field. I don't need it specific to those fields but I don't want them to lose there data when they hit the command button to dump the data into a spreadsheet.

How can I have them see the error msg, hit the ok button and have it take me right back to the screen without losing the data they have alread entered? Basically give them the opporunity to correct their error but not have to reinput 50 fields?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I notice you have not accepted any answers to any of your questions.  Ifyou find an answer usefull you should acept it (click the tick).  If you continue to not accept any answers eventually people will stop answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be specific without the actual code, but add error handlers to your code:

```
Sub SomeRoutine()
    Dim stuff

    On Error GoTo EH

    ' Code

Exit Sub
EH:
    ' Any errors with come here
    If Err.Number = <specific errors to trap> Then
        MsgBox "Oops..."

        'As a debug tools, put a Resume here, 
        ' but be sure to put a break on it, 
        ' and don't leav it in the finished code
        Resume
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It wasn't exactly what I was looking for (I know - hard to tell when I don't give code) however I did actually learn a lot from your example.

Comment: Sorry I wrote more but I ran out of time with it. I had to remove the Resume piece as it was still allowing the incorrect data to move to the spreadsheet.  But like I said I learned a lot with your example...more than I did online or in a book. So I appreciate the time and the example.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you want the user to enter numeric numbers only into the text box - right? This is what I normally do.

In a global module add the following function:

```
Function IFF(c, t, f)
    Dim v
    If c Then v = t Else v = f
    IFF = v
End Function
```

Then in your textbox_change event add the below:

```
Private Sub txtAmount_Change()
    txtAmount.Text = IFF(IsNumeric(txtAmounto.Text), Val(txtAmount.Text), 0)
End Sub
```

This will basically put 0 in the box as soon as the user enters an invalid number.

Hope this helps

Comment: Good answer to the scenario, but not to the actual _question_.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different take on error handlers than that given by chris neilsen

```
Sub SomeRoutine
On Error GoTo ErrHandler  'doesn't matter where you put it
                          'as long as it's before the code you want to protect

'Dim Stuff

     'Do Stuff

ExitRoutine:    'Note the colon(:), which makes this a label
    'Any cleanup that you _always_ want
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case <some error you want to handle specially>
            'special handling
        Case Else
            'default handling, which may include:
            Resume ExitRoutine
    End Select
    Resume
End Sub
```

Note that that last `Resume` will *never* get hit in normal processing (if you've written your error-handling Cases correctly), but will let you set it as "Next Statement" when you're debugging in Break mode. This is an easy way to see *exactly* which statement threw the error.